# NameError creating instance of imported class

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I have a subclassed `Course` class as follows:

```
# course.py
class Course:
    """Represent a single Course"""
    kind = 'Gen Ed'
    def __init__(self, name, number) :
        self._name = name # 'private' instance variable\
        self._number = number
        self.__display()
    def display(self):
        print(self.kind,"Course:" , self._name, self._number, sep=" ")
    __display = display # private copy


class CSCourse(Course):
    """Represent a single CS Course"""
    kind = 'CS' # class variable shared by all CSCourses
    def __init__(self, name, number, language, numberOfPrograms):
        Course.__init__(self, name,  number)
        self._language = language
        self._numberOfPrograms = numberOfPrograms
    def display(self):
        Course.display(self)
        print('Language', self._language,
         'Number Of programs:', self._numberOfPrograms, sep = ' ')
```

I import the module as follows:

```
>>>from course import *
```

This does not throw any exception, but then when I issue the following to call the constructor, I get the error below?

```
>>> cs360=CSCourse("Special Topics", 360, "python", 21)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'CSCourse' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong please? I did also try to see what methods are available in the classes imported. It seems nothing is being imported!

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(Course, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Course' is not defined
>>> inspect.getmembers(CSCourse, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'CSCourse' is not defined
```

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your error but it works for me

Comment: Your code looks fine. Put a `print("something")` at the end of `course.py` to verify it's being imported.

Comment: Thank you folks. I will try it again after I restart my computer. I was very surprised myself as well!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, check if you have circular imports (in file a.py `from b import *` and in file b.py `from a import *`). Python doesn't seem to raise an exception when that happens, but the import doesn't work. Restructuring the code to remove the circular import fixed the problem for me.